# How can I put 2 images next to each other and the images act as my Stripe payment buttons with 2 different charge amounts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, stripe-payments

How can I put the two images right by each other and have the stripe code work correctly? They are different but both buttons end up charging $89. How can I fix this?

I've tried to put each code in a table but it still doesn't work.

```
<img src="images/Silver-Package.png" id="Silver" alt="Silver Sale Price" title="Silver Sale Price"/>

        <form action="http://cheapcruisesandvacations.com/process89.php" method="post" id='paymentForm'>
         <input type='hidden' name='stripeToken'  id='stripeToken' value=''>
         <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail'  id='stripeEmail' value=''>
        </form>

        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
        <script>    
          var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: 'pk_test_Ng4LY005xjAaadkROBTdWU6s',
            image: '[[url of image for the check out form]]',
            token: function(token) {
        $( "#stripeToken" ).val( token.id);
        $( "#stripeEmail" ).val( token.email);
        $( "#paymentForm" ).submit();
            }
          });


        $( "#Silver" ).click(function(event) {
            // Open Checkout with further options
            handler.open({
              name: 'Cruise',
              description: 'Cruise Solo',
              amount: 8900,
            });
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        </script>


    <img src="images/Gold-Package.png" id="Gold" alt="All Inclusive- Cruise, Flight and Hotel" title="All Inclusive- Cruise, Flight and Hotel"/>
```

For some reason the gold button calls `PROCESS89.PHP`

```
<form action="http://cheapcruisesandvacations.com/process399.php" method="post" id='paymentForm'>
         <input type='hidden' name='stripeToken'  id='stripeToken' value=''>
         <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail'  id='stripeEmail' value=''>
        </form>

        <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
        <script>
          var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: 'pk_test_Ng4LY005xjAaadkROBTdWU6s',
            image: '[[url of image for the check out form]]',
            token: function(token) {
        $( "#stripeToken" ).val( token.id);
        $( "#stripeEmail" ).val( token.email);
        $( "#paymentForm" ).submit();
            }
          });


        $( "#Gold" ).click(function(event) {
            // Open Checkout with further options
            handler.open({
              name: 'Gold',
              description: 'Cruise, Flight and Hotel',
              amount: 39900,
            });
            event.preventDefault();
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: use `id`'s only once on a page.  You are calling `$('#paymentForm').submit()`  which always calls the first form

Comment: I changed it to: id='payment'>  and  $( "#payment" ).submit();   once i submit my info it takes me to: http://cheapcruisesandvacations.com/process399.php     the payment does not go through...

Comment: @E-Rod have you gotten a chance to try out the modifications I made to your script?

Comment: @E-Rod give it a shot using the updated JavaScript in my answer or in the live preview link.  I changed the name of your click handlers so that they both have one and I fixed an error i made by placing the wrong id names in one of the click handler open function calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@roullie is correct, instead of using duplicate ids.  You should switch to class names or use unique ids for your forms and input elements.

If you want to use unique ids you could name space them if you only have a couple of packages. So instead of `stripeToken` and `stripeEmail`. You could use silverStripeToken,silverStripeEmail,goldStripeToken and goldStripeEmail or what ever you choose.

Then you could replace the function calls inside of your click handler to use id's similar to previously mentioned(name spaced id's).

Here is an example of how you could restructure your HTML and JavaScript.

Live Example: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/rxXNBQ?editors=1010

HTML:

```
<img src="images/Silver-Package.png" id="Silver" alt="Silver Sale Price" title="Silver Sale Price" />

<form action="http://cheapcruisesandvacations.com/process89.php" method="post" id='silverPaymentForm'>
  <input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' id='SilverStripeToken' value=''>
  <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail' id='SilverStripeEmail' value=''>
</form>


    <img src="images/Gold-Package.png" id="Gold" alt="Gold - All Inclusive- Cruise, Flight and Hotel" title="All Inclusive- Cruise, Flight and Hotel" /> FOR SOME REASON THE GOLD BUTTON CALLS PROCESS89.PHP
    <form action="http://cheapcruisesandvacations.com/process399.php" method="post" id='GoldPaymentForm'>
      <input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' id='goldStripeToken' value=''>
      <input type='hidden' name='stripeEmail' id='goldStripeEmail' value=''>
    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var goldHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_Ng4LY005xjAaadkROBTdWU6s',
  image: '[[url of image for the check out form]]',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#goldStripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#goldStripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#goldPaymentForm").submit();
  }
});

    var silverHandler = StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_Ng4LY005xjAaadkROBTdWU6s',
  image: '[[url of image for the check out form]]',
  token: function(token) {
    $("#silverStripeToken").val(token.id);
    $("#silverStripeEmail").val(token.email);
    $("#silverPaymentForm").submit();
  }
});


$("#Silver").click(function(event) {
  // Open Checkout with further options
  silverHandler.open({
    name: 'Cruise',
    description: 'Cruise Solo',
    amount: 8900,
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});


$("#Gold").click(function(event) {
  // Open Checkout with further options
  goldHandler.open({
    name: 'Gold',
    description: 'Cruise, Flight and Hotel',
    amount: 39900,
  });
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I tried your example but now it only charges $399 for either button... i tried different ways and nothing. I figured that the 1st var handler was silver not gold, correct?

Comment: @E-Rod I forgot that both of your click handlers have the same name. You will need to change the name of one of them because you are reassigning the value of it in your code. I will update my answer.

Comment: @E-Rod give it a try now I had the wrong names in one of your click handlers and I changed the click handler names so that the silver and gold have there own click handlers.

Comment: OMG! thank you... it finally works. I really appreciate your help @Lary Lane

Comment: @E-Rod, Not a problem at all,  I am glad I could help. What do you think about the Stripe payment system so far?

Comment: It's been good so far except for the little bumps I encounter with the coding and I wish they had a customer service line just in case. Other than that, it's been pretty much straight forward and free. By free I mean - stripe give you a lot of freedom to do what ever you desire.